# .NET Core 6, one to many table for multiple tables

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a `medias` table (for uploaded files), and many other tables which upload to this table.

Medias:

```
id, item_id, item_type, path
```

I want to have one-to-many relation between this table and others by `item_id` and `item_type` columns.

How should I define its `ModelBuilder` in `OnModelCreating`?

So when I say:

```
_db.Products.Include(x => x.Medias).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1)
```

it should select those medias with `item_type` of product and `item_id` of 1

Answer (score 1):

> it should select those medias with "item_type" of product and "item_id" of 1

This is not a natural design for a relational database because there's no such thing as a "conditional foreign key".  And EF is not going generate or leverage such a model.

If you create several many-to-many relationships, then EF will create several linking tables.  You can make one of the FKs on a linking table unique if you want to model several one-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

> [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties) for more details

```
example of one to many relationship

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOne<Grade>(s => s.Grade)
                .WithMany(g => g.Students)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.CurrentGradeId);
        }
    
        public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
```